# Is this function continous, differentiable and uniformously continous?

Tags: real-analysis

I tried the following but I get that my concepts are a bit confused coming to this exercise, can someone solve it, please. I think it should be easy but it has been a quite long time for me since I studied continuity,

> $$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
> \cos(2-x) - 2 & x<2 \\
> A & x=2 \\
> e^{x-2}+B & x>2
> \end{cases} $$
>
> For what values of $A$ and $B$ this function is continuous at $(2, -1)$? Is it differentiable at that point? Is it uniformly continuous at $(2, -3)$?
>
> I solved by finding the one-sided limits and it result in $A=-1$ and $B=-2$, for the differentiability I calculated the one-sided limits and the limit acquired wasn't continuous at $(2,-1)$.

Comment: Your values and conclusions are correct. To the best of my knowledge, uniformly continuous at a point makes no sense, and (2, -3) isn't on the graph. Do you mean uniformly continuous on the open interval (2, -3)? Using at there is confusing.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to talk about uniform continuity at a point - particularly a point which isn't represented by the function .- I think you have to clarify what you are asking, because it is a bit confused in the way you have written it.

Comment: I think the question was (2,-3) and i don't think that it means an open interval cause ti would be (-3,2) "@user24142, can you explain why is it differetiable for the found values?

Comment: It isn't differentiable at (2, -1). You correctly said the derivative limit has one value on one side, and another value on the other. The two sided limit therefore doesn't exist, and so the function isn't differentiable there.